# Matlab: Why can't I create an mp4 file using VideoWriter?

Tags: matlab, video, output, frames

I want to remove the background of a video. After that I want to put it into another video and then save it as a new mp4-file. I'm using Windows 10 and I have the following problem that I can't create a new mp4-file after I run my code.

Idea:
I have a car with a greenscreen in the back. I want to cut this car out and put it in front of the street video.
result should be a car driving on the street(video).

code from myScript:

```
clear
close all
v = VideoReader(fullfile('videos', 'carWithGreenscreen.mp4'));
s = VideoReader(fullfile('videos','street.mp4'));

video=zeros(v.Height,v.Width,3,floor(v.Duration/(1/v.FrameRate))-2,'uint8');
t=1;
car = 0.6 ;
values=[0;1;0];
while hasFrame(v)
    Img = im2double(readFrame(v));
    mask = sqrt((values(1)-Img(:, :, 1)).^2+(values(2)-Img(:, :, 2)).^2+(values(3)-Img(:, :, 3)).^2)<car;
    video(:,:,:,t) = imoverlay(im2uint8(Img),mask,[0 0 0]);
    imshow(video(:,:,:,t));
    t=t+1;
end

videoOut = VideoWriter('result.mp4','MPEG-4'); %here I want to create a video%
videoOut.FrameRate=v.FrameRate;
open(videoOut);
moveX=0;
for t=1:1:size(video,4)
    im = video(:,:,:,t);
    mask = im(:,:,1)+im(:,:,2)+im(:,:,3)==0;
    frame=imoverlay(readFrame(s),~mask,[0 0 0]);
    frame=frame+im;
    writeVideo(videoOut,frame);
    imshow(frame);
end
close(videoOut);
```

After I run this code following error occurs:

```
Error using myScript (line 27)
No more frames available to read from file.
line 27: frame=imoverlay(readFrame(s),~mask,[0 0 0]);
```

But at the end it doesn't create a mp4 file... I have tried it out with avi but I only creates an empty .avi file with 0KB...

Comment: I have changed the for loop into a while hasFrame(s) and now this error occurs: >> myScript
Warning: No video frames were written to this file. The file may be invalid. 
> In VideoWriter/close (line 282)
  In myScript (line 32)

Comment: line 32: close(videoOut);

Comment: both videos have the same number of frames 25 and both videos are 10 sec long.

Comment: I should create a video at least...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the problem and it looks like a [codec](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/supported-video-file-formats.html) issue.

I downloaded [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) command line tool, and generated sample (synthetic) videos:

For `carWithGreenscreen.mp4`, I selected `libxvid` codec:

```
ffmpeg -r 2.5 -f lavfi -i testsrc=rate=1:size=320x256 -t 10 -c:v libxvid videos/carWithGreenscreen.mp4
```

For `street.mp4`, I selected `libx264` codec:

```
ffmpeg -r 2.5 -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=rate=1:size=320x256 -t 10 -c:v libx264 videos/street.mp4
```

When executing your script, in MATLAB R2019a in Windows 10, I am getting the same error message:

> Error using myScript (line 27)
>   No more frames available to read from file.

When I select `libxvid` for `street.mp4`, the script is working.

Apparently, MATLAB support for h264 codec is limited.
According to documentation h264 codec is supported, but for some reason it's not working, and I could not find a solution.

---

Here is a workaround solution:

- Use **FFmpeg** for converting `street.mp4` to uncompressed AVI.
  Uncompressed AVI format is preferred because there is no trans-coding (no data loss).
  (Download the static linked last stable version of FFmpeg).

You can execute FFmpeg within MATLAB to preform the conversion (after placing ffmpeg executable in the same folder as your script):

```
% Convert street.mp4 to street.avi (create uncompressed AVI video file)
[status, cmdout] = system(['ffmpeg -y -i ', fullfile('videos','street.mp4'), ' -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 ', fullfile('videos','street.avi')]);

if (status ~= 0)
    display(cmdout); % Displat cmdout in case of an error.
end

%Open street.avi instead of street.mp4
s = VideoReader(fullfile('videos','street.avi'));
```

---

Here is the complete modified code:

```
clear
close all
v = VideoReader(fullfile('videos', 'carWithGreenscreen.mp4'));

%s = VideoReader(fullfile('videos','street.mp4'));

% Convert street.mp4 to street.avi (create uncompressed AVI video file)
[status, cmdout] = system(['ffmpeg -y -i ', fullfile('videos','street.mp4'), ' -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 ', fullfile('videos','street.avi')]);

if (status ~= 0)
    display(cmdout); % Displat cmdout in case of an error.
end

%Open street.avi instead of street.mp4
s = VideoReader(fullfile('videos','street.avi'));

video=zeros(v.Height,v.Width,3,floor(v.Duration/(1/v.FrameRate))-2,'uint8');
t=1;
car = 0.6 ;
values=[0;1;0];
while hasFrame(v)
    Img = im2double(readFrame(v));
    mask = sqrt((values(1)-Img(:, :, 1)).^2+(values(2)-Img(:, :, 2)).^2+(values(3)-Img(:, :, 3)).^2)<car;
    video(:,:,:,t) = imoverlay(im2uint8(Img),mask,[0 0 0]);
    imshow(video(:,:,:,t));
    t=t+1;
end

videoOut = VideoWriter('result.mp4','MPEG-4'); %here I want to create a video%
videoOut.FrameRate=v.FrameRate;
open(videoOut);
moveX=0;
for t=1:1:size(video,4)
    im = video(:,:,:,t);
    mask = im(:,:,1)+im(:,:,2)+im(:,:,3)==0;
    frame=imoverlay(readFrame(s),~mask,[0 0 0]);
    frame=frame+im;
    writeVideo(videoOut,frame);
    imshow(frame);
end
close(videoOut);

%Delete VideoReader objects (force closing the files).
v.delete();
s.delete();
```

Sample last frame (overlay of two synthetic patterns):
[image]

Comment: Thanks A lot it works now with .avi files :). I think Windows 10 has some problems with the mp4 codec because other students with MacOS don't have this problem to create the result file.. You saved my day :)

Comment: Please note: mp4 is not a codec, mp4 is a "container" that may contain video, audio and subtitles streams (and more). A video stream is encoded with a specific codec. mp4 supports many options of video and audio codecs. In case you need to see the codec information, I recommend using [mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) tool.